# How do I write if conditions like these in a macro?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm quite new to macros.
I know how to use if condition using ternary operator.
How do I convert this into a `#define`

```
if(i==j)
            {
                count=count+1;
                break;
            }
```

I try my luck with this but seems like it is wrong:

```
#define ifcount(i,j) ((i)==(j)? count=count+1\
                                    break:0)
```

This is the code i'm trying to convert 
http://pastebin.com/i7Tuyh00

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert it into ternary? You can write `if` very well in the macro. Just don't forget backslashes in the line breaks...

Comment: Don't abuse macros. Leave the break in the code, so it will make sense to anyone who reads it.

Comment: @haccks it is in 2nd line i want if condition is not true nothing happens

Comment: Don't change control flow of the outer code inside a macro! No one will understand what your code does. That includes yourself after some weeks/months!

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi,i saw this therefore i thought this would be used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989298/is-it-possible-to-use-a-if-statement-inside-define

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using (abusing) macros to change the flow of the program is usually a bad idea, because the people that will read your code (yourself in a few years) may get surprised by unexpected jumps in the program flow.

That said, your problem has nothing to do with the ternary operator. Actually the ternary operator cannot contain a break in its right side, only expressions.

But macros are allmighty, so you can just do:

```
#define ifcount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count=count+1; break; }
```

The main problem with this macro is that people will write a `;` when using it, and it will break badly if it is used between another `if /else` pair, without braces:

```
if (...)
    ifcount(a,b);
else // <--- syntax error because the previous ; breaks the if /else relation
    ...;
```

The standard solution is to use the `do/while(0)` idiom:

```
#define do { ifcount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count=count+1; break; } } while (0)
```

But that will not work because the `break` will break this inner `while`, not the one you want (credit to @abelenky) below.

The only other C statement that allows a compound statement and ends with a `;` is this one:

```
#define ifcount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count=count+1; break; } else
```

The problem is that if you forget to add the `;` when using `ifcount(i,j)`, instead of a compiler error you will get a silently compiling and surprisingly change in behavior.

Comment: ok thanks but what is this sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989298/is-it-possible-to-use-a-if-statement-inside-define

Comment: @HumayunAkhtar Are you trying to control the flow of a program, such as with `break`?  Or are you trying to assign the results of an expression?  That question you linked is trying to assign something.  Your question isn't about that.

Comment: @Terminator: It looks like you are trying to convert a program to obfuscating macros just for the sake of it, and that makes no sense whatsoever. I'm guessing that it is some kind of weird assignment...

Comment: @Terminator: In C there are expressions and there are statements. A macro can be one or the other (or even none) but not an statement and an expression at the same time. `if` is a statement, so is `break`, but `?:` is an expression.

Comment: @rodrigo this is a weird assignment and i knew nothing about macro i'm learning on all interent and trying to solve it

Comment: The trailing semicolon in the macro (`#define ifcount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count=count+1; break; } else ;`) is bad news.  In the context: `if (…) ifcount(i, j); else …`, the trailing semicolon in the macro makes this code into a syntax error — the `else` in this code is invalid.  You could, I suppose, omit that trailing semicolon in the macro definition (but that's icky — it would require copious comments).  But this is why people use the `#define ifcount(i, j) do { if ((i) == (j)) { count++; break; } while (0)` meme; it doesn't break the syntax of `if (…) ifcount(i, j); else …`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right, of course. My intention was to write the _dangling else_, without the semicolon, but that is so unnatural to write. I'll change it to the `while (0)` thing.

Comment: Note what [abelenky](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky) [told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125854/how-do-i-write-if-conditions-like-these-in-a-macro/39126059?noredirect=1#comment65601630_39126055) me.  Aaargh!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Ouch! I know the dangling `else` will come handy sometime... reverting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need to use the ternary (`?:`) operator.
So here is your macro using an if-statement.

```
#define IfCount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count++; break; }
```

**Usage:**

```
IfCount(x,5);
```

---

Okay, what do you guys think of this?

```
#define IfCount(i,j) if ((i)==(j)) { count++; break; } do{}while(0)
```

The final, isolated `do-while-0` serves a couple of purposes:

- Its a place to hang a semi-colon, so the macro usage looks like "normal" C and ends with a semi-colon.
- It prevents an inadvertent else-statement afterwards, because the syntax `do{}while(0) else` is invalid.

Is there anything else it should take care of?

Comment: This fails in the context: `if (…) IfCount(x, 5); else …` because the else here is a syntax error.  That is why people use the `#define IfCount(i, j) do { if ((i) == (j)) { count++; break; } while (0)` meme; it doesn't break the syntax of `if (…) IfCount(i, j); else …`.

Comment: Your version won't work either:  The `break`-statement will break out of the `do-while(0)` loop, and not the outer, user-written loop.

Comment: Oh —— futz!  You're right, of course.  Grrr!  Don't do what the macro's trying to do, then.

Comment: Honestly, the attempt at a macro here is BS and pointless obfuscation.   The OP would be better off writing simple, clear, explicit code without macros. :)

Comment: Absolutely — the macro is misguided, and my attempt to fix one problem didn't help. A numbered break (`break 2;` as in [shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) scripts) would fix it if C supported it, but it doesn't.

Comment: @abelenky this is the code i have to convert it to macro no matter what http://pastebin.com/i7Tuyh00

Comment: @Terminator: the code shown in the pastebin won't benefit at all from using a macro (which is invoked once).  Were you not under constraints from some tutor, submitting that code with a macro such as the proposed one would be cause for immediate loss of marks and/or face — it is pointless to make a macro except as a pedagogic exercise.  I'd be tempted to use: `#define if_condition_body(condition, body) if (condition) { body; } else` and then invoke `if_condition_body(i == j, count++; break)` where the semicolon (and `break`) in the macro invocation makes it clear this isn't a regular function.